# Validate Form Before calling modal

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, twitter-bootstrap-3, form-submit

I have a form with a submit button and when the button is clicked it opens a confirm modal which is a Twitter Bootstrap modal. If the modals confirm button is clicked it will submit the for but the validation happens after the modal button is clicked instead of the form button. I am also using jQuery Validation

I want to get the form to validate first, stop the submit throught, show the confirm modal, then if confirmed submit the form.

I realise this may not be possible but I am at a loss how to do it.

```
<form action="URL" method="POST" id="validation-form" class="confirm-form">

    <label for="deletion_reason" class="col-xs-3 col-lg-4 control-label">Select One</label>

    <select data-placeholder="Select one..." data-rule-required="true">
        <option></option>
        <option value="1">One</option>
        <option value="2">Two</option>
        <option value="3">Three</option>
        <option value="4">Four</option>
    </select>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger white-text modal-toggle" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-dialog" data-modal-type="form-confirm" data-modal-title="Delete Transaction" data-modal-text="Are you sure you want to delete this transaction?"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Delete</button>
    <a href="http://localhost.testing/form-modals.html"><button type="button" class="btn"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> Cancel</button></a>

</form>

$('.modal-toggle').click(function(e){
    // modal data assigned
    modalType = $(this).data('modal-type').toLowerCase();
    modalTitle = $(this).data('modal-title');
    modalText = $(this).data('modal-text');

    // check which buttons to output
    if(modalType == "confirm"){     
        modalUrl = $(this).data('modal-confirm-url');
        modalOptions = '<a href="' + modalUrl + '" class="btn btn-primary showhouse-colour"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</a><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> No</button>';
    }else if(modalType == "alert"){
        modalOptions = '<button class="btn btn-primary showhouse-colour" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Ok</button>';
    }else if(modalType == 'form-confirm'){
        modalOptions = '<button class="btn showhouse-colour white-text" data-dismiss="modal" id="confirm-form-yes"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</button><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> No</button>';
    }

    // output modal footer buttons
    $('.modal-title').html(modalTitle);
    $('.modal-text').html(modalText);
    $('.modal-footer').html(modalOptions);

    // if form-confirm, submit it
    $('#confirm-form-yes').click(function(){
        $('.confirm-form').submit();
    });

});
```

Comment: I dont understand your issue? Can you give a specific problem/error?

Comment: When I click delete on form the modal appears then user clicks ok on modal then form is validated and submitted. I want to click delete -> form gets validated -> then modal appears -> ok submits it

Comment: Your code is incomplete.  If you're using the jQuery Validate plugin, then there should be a call to `.validate()` in there someplace.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so you have your click event:

`$('.modal-toggle').click(function(e){`

Not sure with which parmas you are validating but use this:

[.validate()](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/)

Rest of your script (open modal+submit):

```
modalType = $(this).data('modal-type').toLowerCase();
modalTitle = $(this).data('modal-title');
modalText = $(this).data('modal-text');

// check which buttons to output
if(modalType == "confirm"){     
    modalUrl = $(this).data('modal-confirm-url');
    modalOptions = '<a href="' + modalUrl + '" class="btn btn-primary showhouse-colour"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</a><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> No</button>';
}else if(modalType == "alert"){
    modalOptions = '<button class="btn btn-primary showhouse-colour" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Ok</button>';
}else if(modalType == 'form-confirm'){
    modalOptions = '<button class="btn showhouse-colour white-text" data-dismiss="modal" id="confirm-form-yes"><i class="icon-ok"></i> Yes</button><button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true"><i class="icon-ban-circle"></i> No</button>';
}

// output modal footer buttons
$('.modal-title').html(modalTitle);
$('.modal-text').html(modalText);
$('.modal-footer').html(modalOptions);

// if form-confirm, submit it
$('#confirm-form-yes').click(function(){
    $('.confirm-form').submit();
});
});
```

May I suggest NOT building a modal via JS but rather have it hidden in the page with the events attached to it, displaying it after validation then sending it.

Hope this helps!

Comment: The modal is actually being trigger when i click the button with data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal-dialog" The line "$('.modal-toggle').click(function(e)" is just used to gather the data tags that are being passed in the button

Answer (score 0):

So what you want is to validate the form on the form submit button then do the validation,

and once the form is validated you wish to open the modal with confirm submission prompt.

If confirmed then submit.

So, follow these steps:

1.

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-danger white-text" 
          onclick="return ValidateForm();">
```

2.
 Make a div with id `myModal` and place the content that you want to show the user for
 confirmation dialog.

3.

```
    if (jQuery().validate) {
    var removeSuccessClass = function(e) {
        $(e).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success');
    }
    $('#validation-form').validate({
        errorElement: 'span', //default input error message container
        errorClass: 'help-block', // default input error message class
        focusInvalid: false, // do not focus the last invalid input
        ignore: "",

        invalidHandler: function (event, validator) { 
         //display error alert on form submit              

        },

        highlight: function (element) { // hightlight error inputs
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-success').addClass
          ('has-error'); // set error class to the control group
        },

        unhighlight: function (element) { // revert the change dony by hightlight
            $(element).closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error'); 
          // set error class to the control group

            setTimeout(function(){removeSuccessClass(element);}, 3000);
        },

        success: function (label) {
            $('#myModal').modal('show');
            label.closest('.form-group').removeClass('has-error').addClass
        ('has-success'); // set success class to the control group
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I am using the jquery validation script for my validation an im having trouble locating where the form gets submitted

Comment: Where have you put the Jquery Validation call? I can't see any validate() function call.

Comment: I have it in my external js file. I edited your answer to show the validation call